# Does a cafe proprietor have a duty to look after an item of lost property?

Tags: united-kingdom, theft

This involves the UK. I went to the park with my grandson and his friend to play football. We had quite an expensive, high quality size 4 football. After playing around for a while we went to the park café for a drink and something to eat. Carelessly we left without the football, so I returned there later in the day to see if they had it. The person in charge told me that it had been noticed, but had been put somewhere - he didn't know where. After a brief search he said I would have to go back the following day when his colleague would know where it was.

When I returned the next day I was met by the same individual I had seen previously. He told me rather tersely that he had last seen the ball when some kids were kicking it around, and he had no idea where it was, and it was probably taken by someone. When I expressed surprise that, knowing it was ours, he hadn't taken care of it, he got very defensive and kept repeating himself saying we should not have left it behind - a truism, if ever there was one!

My own contention is that the café has been an accessory to theft.

The café has now installed notices which state that they cannot be responsible for people's lost property. However these were not there when the ball was left behind.

Comment: No, it's not their responsibility it's the responsibility of the owner. While it's a good deed but they are not legally required to take care of lost property unless they are asked and agreed by any individual.

Comment: @Santosh But in this case, on day 1 the fellow informed that the item had been found and put to one side. On day 2 he dismissed it as an irrelevance saying that some kids must have taken it. So he had knowingly been in possession of someone's property and had allowed it to be stolen. It is not the cost of the football that bothers me - just that the guy was so downright uncivil about it. My own instinct, had I found such a thing, would have been to put it behind the counter in case the owner returned.

Comment: Well if it was found and kept aside on day 1 why didn't you ask for it then on that same day?

Comment: @Santosh Because he said he couldn't find it. I cannot entirely accept that a person finding something does not have a duty to see that it is taken care of. Suppose I find a wallet on a park seat with £1,000 in it. Do I have a right to keep it?

Comment: If the manager was mistaken on day one and terse on day two out of personal embarrassment?

Comment: @user662852 What his behaviour tells me was that he saw the ball on day 1, recognised it as something someone had left behind, but took no action to stop someone else stealing it. Ok - it was only a football. But let's say it had been a diamond ring valued at £100,000. The title in the property must still vest in its original owner. And "theft" I believe is defined as "taking something with intent permanently to deprive the owner of it". Clearly the ball has been stolen, either by the person who carried it away, or by the café manager who told them they could have it.

Comment: @WS2 I think value is important here. I've always heard that if you find something valued over x amount then you have a legal duty to hand it over the authorities, which you may claim as your own if the original owner does not reclaim it after a time. I doubt the football falls above that amount. Then there's a whole process for "abandoned" property, such as cars and houses, but, again, that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: @fredsbend Value is clearly important for all practical purposes. But I found it depressing that a business proprietor, depending for his livelihood on the goodwill of the public, would act in such a cavalier way with what was obviously the property of a child. I was minded to complain to the City Council, the park's owners, who licensed the café premises to the operator, but eventually managed to put the twit out of my mind.